# why do i get a deformed mesh in weight paint mode and object mode but in Edit mode, the mesh appears the way it should?

Tags: mesh

I came a long way modelling this character until i reached the weight painting step. In edit mode, my mesh seems okay though when i swich to weight paint mode or object mode, it gets deformed along the thighs...perhaps i could have grabbed some vertices unknowingly bt how to i get them back to their original position? I tried deleting the vertices assigned to the thigh-bone but still the overall result is the same..Please help.

Comment: If your mesh is rigged, the result of deformations by armature won't be seen in Edit mode unless checking option of the modifier. Try looking in the Pose mode if something has changed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a problem like this before. If you have not been able to fall X the mesh by deleting the weight groups then try the following. 1.Go into edit mode. 2. Select all the mesh 3. Press "Shift"+"d" to duplicate the mesh 4. Press "p" and separate mesh by selection.
This will leave you with a new undeformed mesh as a separate object. And the original mesh if you decide to come back to it.